# CDH-5.4.0, spark-on-yarn, cluster-mode and Java

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I have a `CDH-5.4.0`, 4-nodes cluster with spark-on-yarn.
I have an environment variable `YARN_CONF_DIR` pointing to the directory that contains a copy of the configuration files taken from one of the cluster members (where the address of yarn resource manager).
I want to run a spark jobs from java:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().
            setMaster("yarn-cluster").// "yarn-cluster" or "yarn-client"
            setAppName("SparX");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
String path = "hdfs://virtual-machine-12.local:8020/mockRecords.csv";
JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile(path);
System.out.println(textFile.count());
```

If I run the program in `yarn-cluster` mode I get a `NullPointerException`:

```
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.sparkContextInitialized(ApplicationMaster.scala:580)
```

If I run the program in `yarn-client` the code hangs after `new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf)`

Any idea what am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: does the program execute in local mode?

Comment: what do you mean by "local mode"? the machine that runs the program is not part of the cluster. If I SSH to one of the nodes I can use spark-submit

Comment: if you use setMaster("local") instead of what you have does it run without error?

Comment: setting it to "local" makes the driver run locally. It connects to HDFS, though. I'm sure it have something to do with the configuration files, just can't put my fingers on it...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR points to the directory which contains the (client side) configuration files for the Hadoop cluster.

For your CDH-5.4.0 cluster, you can download configuration from `Cluster/yarn/Actions/Download Client Configuration`, unzip it and set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `YARN_CONF_DIR` points to this directory.